# TicTacToe using two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a program that does the game TicTacToe. I have finished creating 
all the methods and I just need to create the driver program. Before creating the 
driver program, I tried to just print the board along with a character but I don't 
think my methods are correct. Here is what my error looks like:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at TicTacToeBoard.move(TicTacToeBoard.java:75)
at TicTacToe.main(TicTacToe.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:271)
```

Here are my two programs:

This is my driver program that I can't seem to complete. The last thing  that will be shown is the
template so that you have the idea of how each program works.

```
class TicTacToe
{
 public static void main(String [] args)
 { 
  //System.out.println("Welcome! Tic-Tac-Toe is a two player game.");
  //System.out.println("Enter player one's name: ");

  TicTacToeBoard game = new TicTacToeBoard();
  System.out.println(game.toString());

  //int count = 0;


  game.move('x', 1, 3); 
  // game.move('o', 1, 1);

  /* while (game.gameWon() !true || count != 9)
     {
      System.out.print(game.move()); 
      System.out.print(game.isEmpty()); 
      }*/   
     }
    }
```

This is where all the methods are......

```
class TicTacToeBoard
{
 private char [][] board = new char[3][3];
 String b;

 // This a new constructor that creates a tic-tac-toe board
 public TicTacToeBoard()
 {
  for (int rows = 0; rows < board.length; rows++)// creates rows
  {
   for (int columns = 0; columns <board[rows].length;columns++)// creates columns
   {
    //System.out.println("| ");
     board[rows][columns] = ' ';
    //System.out.println(" |\n" );
    }
   }
 }

  // creates a string form of the tic-tac-toe board and allows the user
  // to access it during the game.
  public String toString()
  {
   String b = "";

   // creates a vertical bar at the beginning and the end of each row
   for (int rows = 0; rows < board.length; rows++)
   {
     b += "| ";
     // adds a space for each row and column character in tic-tac-toe board.
     for (int columns = 0; columns < board[rows].length; columns++)
     {
      b += board[rows][columns] + " ";  
      }
       b += "|\n";// prints a | space space space | and breaks off to create two new lines.
      }
       return b; // prints the tic-tac-toe board to be accessed by the user.
     }

String move(char x, int rows, int columns)
{ 
 String b = "";

 // creates a vertical bar at the beginning and the end of each row
 for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++)
 {
   b += "| ";

  for (int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++)
  {
   b += board[r][c] + " ";  //prints 3 spaces on each line. 
    // prints string character from user input if row and column not equal to zero 
   if (board[rows - 1][columns - 1] >= 0 && board[rows - 1][columns - 1] <= 2 )
   {
    board[rows - 1][columns - 1] = x;// prints character in the specified index from user input 
    b += board[rows - 1][columns - 1];// prints out the board and the new character in specified space.
     } 
      else if (board[rows - 1][columns - 1] < 0)   // makes user pick another choice
      return "ILLEGAL MOVE, TRY AGAIN!"; 
      // adds a space for each row and column character in tic-tac-toe board.
     }
      b += "|\n";// prints a | space space space | and breaks off to create two new lines.
    }  
     return b; // prints the tic-tac-toe board to be accessed by the user.

   }

  // checks if a space character is empty
  void isEmpty(char x, int row, int col)
  {
   if (board [row - 1][col - 1] == ' ')
    board[row - 1][col - 1] = x;
   else // makes user pick another row and column if space character is not empty
   System.out.println("ILLEGAL CHOICE, PICK AGAIN!");
   }
  // checks if game is won   
 public boolean gameWon(int row, int col)
 {  
  if ((board[2][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[2][0] == board[0][2]))
   return true;
  else if ((board[2][0] != board[1][1]) && (board[2][0] != board[0][2]))
   return false;   

  if ((board[2][2] == board[1][1])&& (board[2][2] == board[0][0]))
   return true;
  else if ((board[2][2] != board[1][1])&& (board[2][2] != board[0][0]))
   return false;   

  if ((board[0][0] == board[1][0]) && (board[0][0] == board[2][0]))
   return true;
  else if ((board[0][0] != board[1][0]) && (board[0][0] != board[2][0]))
   return false;        

  if ((board[0][1] == board[1][1]) && (board[0][1] == board[2][1]))
   return true;
  else if ((board[0][1] != board[1][1]) && (board[0][1] != board[2][1]))
   return false;        

  if ((board[0][2] == board[1][2]) && (board[0][2] == board[2][2]))
   return true;
  else if ((board[0][2] != board[1][2]) && (board[0][2] != board[2][2]))
   return false;   

  if ((board[0][0] == board[0][1]) && (board[0][0] == board[0][2]))
   return true;
  else if ((board[0][0] != board[0][1]) && (board[0][0] != board[0][2]))
   return false;   

  if ((board[1][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[1][0] == board[1][2]))
   return true;
  else if ((board[1][0] != board[1][1]) && (board[1][0] != board[1][2]))
   return false;     

  if ((board[2][0] == board[2][1]) && (board[2][0] == board[2][2]))
   return true;
  else 
   return false;
 }
}
```

Here is the template for the whole thing!!!!!

```
class TicTacToe
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
       TicTacToeBoard b = new TicTacToeBoard();

       while (game not over)
       {
            swtich player
            increment turn counter

            until user enters a valid move    
            {
                  prompt for move
             }

            make move
            b.makeMove (player, row, col);

            print board    
            System.out.println(b);
       }

       print outcome
  }
 }


 class TicTacToeBoard
 {
   private char [][] board = ...;

   public TicTacToeBoard()
   {
      initialize board with spaces
    }

   public void makeMove (char c, int row, int col)
   {
        store symbol in specified position
    }

   public boolean isEmpty(int row, int col)
   {
        return true if square is unfilled
    }

   public boolean gameWon()
   {
        check board for a win
    }

   public String toString ()
   {
        return String representation of board
    }

 }
```

Comment: Array indices begin with `0`. Your column of `3` is not a valid element of the array `board[R]` here, hence your exception. Try `2` :-)

Answer (score 4):

Programming languages are unforgiving for errors and force rigor and care on us.

Your code is quite difficult for us to read and thus for both us and you to debug, starting with your indentation which is all over the place, but there are also careless errors, especially this one:

```
for (int r = 0; r < board.length; rows++)
```

Do you see what is wrong here? `r` is not the same as `rows`, and you can't use one as the index for the loop and then increment the other. You're using *both* of these variables inside of the loop. There are several other careless errors in the code as well.

I recommend that you start over but be much more careful with your code and be especially careful with your indentation. If you don't line up your curly braces correctly, you will not see when one code block ends and another begins (nor will we!).

Oh, and next time, please let us know which lines of your code are causing your error. It will be much easier to help you if we don't have to guess this information.

**Edit**
Your new code indentation is some better, but still is off. This is what you have:

```
String move(char x, int rows, int columns)
{ 
 String b = "";

 // creates a vertical bar at the beginning and the end of each row
 for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++)
 {
   b += "| ";

  for (int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++)
  {     
   b += board[rows][columns] + " ";
```

and this is what I recommend:

```
String move(char x, int rows, int columns) {
  String b = "";

  // creates a vertical bar at the beginning and the end of each row
  for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++) {
     b += "| ";

     for (int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++) {

        // let's check to see what the variables hold!
        System.out.printf("rows: %d, columns %d, r: %d, c: %d%n", rows, columns, r, c); 
        b += board[rows][columns] + " "; // **** the offending line ****
```

Even more important, note the result from the printf statement followed immediately by the exception:

```
rows: 1, columns 3, r: 0, c: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

So here it is the column variable that holds the value of 3 and causes your array to explode. You will need to track back to see how you call this method and why it is passing a 3 into the column parmaeter.

**Edit 2**
On re-review of your latest post, you're still hard coding your move method to accept a 3 as the column parameter:

```
game.move('x', 1, 3);
```

Fix that first and foremost. That parameter **can't** be 3.

Comment: Ok well, I am still gettting the same error message...I just can't seem to figure it out!!!!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels see my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024014/tictactoe-using-two-dimensional-arrays#comment16046253_12024014)

Comment: I followed your message about the loop....if i switched it to rows, I would get a duplicate variable message. So I just made them r and c

Comment: it is still pointing at the same lines.....75 in TicTacToeBoard and 24 in TicTacToe :)

Comment: All my braces match, and are indented so that I can understand it but I am still getting the same message that I had told you previously with the lines

Comment: Ok so I just edited it....it looks almost the same like the original except with the new code. It still giving me the same message on line 24 in TicTacToe and 75 in TicTacToeBoard. It prints the board but not with the character

Comment: @Alex: please see **Edit 2**. Also, please delete any comments as soon as the cease being relevant, else the moderators will swoop down on us and stop us from "chatting".

Comment: By the way, if you're having problems with formatting your code, most popular IDEs have an auto format feature. for Eclipse it's Ctrl + Shft + F and for Netbeans it's Alt + Shift + F. Use those if you're too lazy to re-indent all your code, it will make life a whole lot easier.

Comment: Ok, different problem...it is not giving me the error this time but it is only printing the board. It is still not printing the character.

Comment: You know the drill -- show the code and the output and any error messages (if any that occur). This may be considered a different problem since you initial problem, that of the AIOOB's has been solved, so  you may wish to close this, accept an answer, and ask your new question with your new code and its results, etc...

Comment: I just created a new question called TicTacToe2 if you want to look it over